# Deserializing 2D JSON array to bean using GSON

Tags: java, json, multidimensional-array, gson

I have not been able to map this nested array rows->elements to my javabean. Is gson actually capable of handling this kind of mapping? I also tried a different approach, which you can see if you look at the commented out Java code.

```
package scratch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*
{
  "rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "897 mi",
              "value" : 1443464
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "14 hours 32 mins",
              "value" : 52327
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "378 mi",
              "value" : 607670
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "6 hours 22 mins",
              "value" : 22908
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
]

}
*/

public class GeoZipCodesBean2 {

    //    private Elem[][] rows;

    //    public Elem[][] getRows() {
    //        return rows;
    //    }
    //
    //    public void setRows(Elem[][] rows) {
    //        this.rows = rows;
    //    }

    private List<List<Elem>>rows;

    public List<List<Elem>> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(List<List<Elem>> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }



    public static class Elem {
        private Distance distance;
        private Duration duration;

        public Distance getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        public void setDistance(Distance distance) {
            this.distance = distance;
        }

        public Duration getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
        }
    }

    public static class Distance {
        private String text;
        private Integer value;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static class Duration {
        private String text;
        private Integer value;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}

GeoZipCodesBean2 geoZipCodesBean2 = new Gson().fromJson(str, GeoZipCodesBean2.class);
```

Comment: Looking at your json, `rows` is pointing to a list of elements rather than to a list of list of elements. May be the json generating part has some problem. Also, there are some errors in the json. You have a trailing comma in the end. You can validate your json here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Narendra, rows is an array and elements is an array as well. so it's actually a 2D array.

Comment: Your code says  `rows` is a `List<List<Element>>`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the JSON format for your `GeoZipCodesBean2` object (if `rows` is a `List<List<Elem>>`)

```
{
    "rows": [
        [
            {
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "897 mi",
                            "value": 1443464
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "14 hours 32 mins",
                            "value": 52327
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "378 mi",
                            "value": 607670
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "6 hours 22 mins",
                            "value": 22908
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is the code for converting to/from json

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    GeoZipCodesBean2 geo = new GeoZipCodesBean2();
    List<List<Elem>> rows = new ArrayList<List<Elem>>();
    List<Elem> elem = new ArrayList<Elem>();
    Elem e1 = new Elem();
    Distance d = new Distance();
    d.setText("fads");
    d.setValue(1234);
    e1.setDistance(d);
    elem.add(e1);
    rows.add(elem);
    geo.setRows(rows);
    String json = gson.toJson(geo);
    //The following prints {"rows":[[{"distance":{"text":"fads","value":1234}}]]}
    System.out.println(json);
    json = "{\"rows\":[[{\"distance\":{\"text\":\"fads\",\"value\":1234}, \"status\":\"OK\"}]]}";
    GeoZipCodesBean2 geo2 = gson.fromJson(json, GeoZipCodesBean2.class);
    //The following prints 1234
    System.out.println(geo2.getRows().get(0).get(0).getDistance().getValue());
}
```

Comment: you are right. This JSON is correct for my current code, which means my Java code is wrong for the original JSON. Actually, initially my instance variable was "private List<Elem>rows", but even though those two Elems get instantiated by GSON, the Distance and Duration inside them are left as null - I don't know why this happening. Do I have to map everything in JSON  to the bean when I am using gson?

Comment: Actually there are other fields that I omitted. Everything gets initialized except fields (Distance and Duration) I put  inside the "Elem".

Comment: @Onur Added code, looks like the distance object is getting initialized properly.

Comment: this is not for the original JSON tho. This does not work with the original JSON that I posted. My current code with "List<Elem>rows" here [link](http://pastebin.com/VdipwWLi). I need it to work with the original JSON. this is my test class [link](http://pastebin.com/wSnbvBA0)

Comment: @Onur The problem is that your json and your object strcuture do not match. After fixing the json problems the code will look like this http://pastebin.com/h1fv4wzV . You have to change your object structure to match the json returned by Google map api.

Comment: I solved the problem @Narendra. I was misinterpreting the JSON. "rows" is not a 2D array. It is a single dimensional array of objects (hash tables), and each of those objects has one key named 'elements' which is another single dimensional array of objects. Latest working version [link](http://pastebin.com/kFasUzPe)