# How to parse JSON 2D array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I have json data like this:

```
{ 
    "err_code": "0", 
    "date":"20130121",
    "time_from":"1242", 
    "range":"5",
    "data":[['12313123','BOOK CODE CYFV3M
NUM CODE 3789850802600'],['089898989','BOOK CODE 1F45MN
NUM CODE 3787510241500']] 
}
```

and I've tried this program:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonKAI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jStr = "{\"err_code\":\"0\",\"date\":\"20130121\",\"time_from\":\"1242\",\"range\":\"5\",\"data\":[['12313123','BOOK CODE CYFV3M NUM CODE 3789850802600'],['089898989','BOOK CODE 1F45MN NUM CODE 3787510241500']] }";
// Replace this try catch block for all below subsequent examples
        try {
            JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(jStr);
            JSONArray rows = rootObject.getJSONArray("data"); // Get all JSONArray data
            int count = rows.length();
            for(int i=0 ; i< count; i++){
                JSONArray jsonArr = rows.getJSONArray(i);
                System.out.println("jsonObject " + i + ": " + jsonArr);
                //for(int j=0 ; j< count; j++){
                //JSONArray jArr = rows.getJSONArray(j);
                //String s = jArr.toString();
                //System.out.println("jsonObject " +s);
            }}
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
jsonObject 0: ["12313123","BOOK CODE CYFV3M NUM CODE 3789850802600"]
jsonObject 1: ["089898989","BOOK CODE 1F45MN NUM CODE 3787510241500"]
```

I wanna ask how to get/parse from
    ["12313123","BOOK CODE CYFV3M NUM CODE 3789850802600"]

to `12313123` and `BOOK CODE CYFV3M NUM CODE 3789850802600` (without '[' and '"')?
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend using the Gson library instead. Your 2-dimensional json array would be created as a List of Lists. This answer might help if you would like to explore that possibility: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7925602/877472

Comment: You have an array.  Extract the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
        String jStr = "{\"err_code\":\"0\",\"date\":\"20130121\",\"time_from\":\"1242\",\"range\":\"5\",\"data\":[['12313123','BOOK CODE CYFV3M NUM CODE 3789850802600'],['089898989','BOOK CODE 1F45MN NUM CODE 3787510241500']] }";
        try {
          JSONObject rootObject = JSONObject.fromObject(jStr);
          JSONArray rows = rootObject.getJSONArray("data"); // Get all JSONArray data
          int count = rows.size();
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            JSONArray jsonArr = rows.getJSONArray(i);
            System.out.println("jsonArray " + i + ": " + jsonArr);
            for (Object o : jsonArr) {          
              System.out.println(o);
            }
          }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the below example:

```
String str = "{\"items\":[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],\"ans\":[[\"1\",\"2\"],[\"Glad\",\"Good\"]]}";
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
                JSONArray jsonArry1 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items");

                int[][] ints1 = new int[jsonArry1.length()][3];

                for(int i = 0; i<jsonArry1.length(); i++){
                    JSONArray jsa1 = jsonArry1.getJSONArray(i);

                    for(int j = 0; j<jsa1.length();j++){
                        ints1[i][j] = jsa1.getInt(j);
                    }

                }
```

I tested and it works!